# Hide import in library (Python)

Tags: python, import

How do I hide imports in my library?

library.py

```
import numpy as np
```

test.py

```
import library
print(dir(library))
```

result (python3 test.py)

```
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__',
 '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 
 'np']
```

Problem: `np` is a module of the library.

What is a sensible way to hide the library that I used for writing a library?

Comment: What is a sensible *reason* for hiding a library?

Comment: it is an internal import and is not part of the api of my library. Can anyone explain why this is not sensible? I don't think `fftpack` is in `dir(scipy.fftpack)`.

Comment: Bending over backwards to hide your implementation is not pythonic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to mark the import as not a part of your public API, give the module a name with a leading underscore:

```
import numpy as _np
```

If you want to hide the name completely, you'll need to perform the import inside each function of your module that uses NumPy:

```
def f1(stuff):
    import numpy as np
    ...

def f2(stuff):
    import numpy as np
    ...

...
```

Comment: that leading underscore makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You could organize your code as a module with an `__init__.py` file specifying what your library provides. Thus, you could have something like

Actual library implementation:

```
# ./library/mycode.py
import numpy

def f():
    pass

def g():
    pass
```

init file:

```
# ./library/__init__.py
from library.mycode import f, g
```

and now we test it:

```
# ./test.py
import library
print dir(library)
```

Note that while this hides the numpy import from the top-level attributes of your library, a sufficiently determined user can still get at it via `library.mycode.numpy`. Still, this effectively demonstrates to your user what you wish to expose as your library's API and fits in with Python's philosophy that "We are all adults here."

Comment: kind of tedious to list every class/function for public api in the `from library.mycode import f, g`

Comment: One way to make this a bit quicker is through thoughtful use of the `__all__` variable. It's a good idea to have this defined anyway, and then one could use `from library.mycode import *`